# Angular 2 using the top level router outlet for all descendants

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a top level component that contains all the features a user can get access to, like an account or a profile page, but also features that have their own child pages. I got a deeply nested route tree this way, however I currently don't want the same structure to be represented on the view. Every component's content should be shown in the top level router-outlet contained in UserComponent's HTML. In short a user's profile information (*/user/profile*) and product creation for the user's 9th shop (*/user/shop/9/create*) should be forwarded to the exact same router outlet.

This is how the relevant part of my *app-routing.modules.ts* looks like now:

```
path: 'user',
component: UserComponent,
canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
canActivateChild: [AuthenticationGuard],
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/user/profile',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    redirectTo: '/user/profile',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    component: AccountComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'shop',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: ShopComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'stores',
            component: StoresComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'modify',
            component: ShopModifyComponent
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'create',
        component: ShopCreateComponent
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

There are routes that don't even have a component. For example *user/shop* currently has now meaning, however when an ID is provided *user/shop/123* then I want to show that shop's data. There are also routes that should contain multiple parameters like *user/shop/123/product/321*.

I tried all the different configurations I could find, creating named outlets then calling them, but usually I either got an error that there was no primary outlet found or that it couldn't match the provided URL.

Is there a simple way of telling all descendants (no matter how deep they are) to use the top level router outlet?

Comment: What do you mean by forwarded to same router outlet? Should it be rendered the same, or a redirect shoud be made?

Comment: I meant that the content associated with the /user/profile and /user/shop/9/create routes (for example) should be loaded to the same <router-outlet> tag that is located in UserComponent's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you assign 'UserComponent' to 'shop' route configuration?

If you need to use 'UserComponent' in two different purpose (one for user based detail other for layout of shop information) then you can have two outlets in 'UserComponent' template and assign that other outlet name to 'shop' route configuration.

For example, you might do like this

UserComponent

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="shop"></router-outlet>
```

and then your route configuration

```js
{
    path: 'shop',
    component: UserComponent,
    outlet: 'shop',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: ShopComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'stores',
            component: StoresComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'modify',
            component: ShopModifyComponent
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'create',
        component: ShopCreateComponent
      },
    ]
  }
```

in the case that you don't want to show anything while routing to ShopComponent then you can just put only tag "router-outlet" in them and nothing else.